# To click on dropdown multiple selection via selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need help to click on the menu on the right (1), to chose the 'Price to Book' option in order to read the text ('UCTT 1.8x) of the label (2).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7X6i.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help.

The website is: https://simplywall.st/stocks/us/semiconductors/nasdaq-uctt/ultra-clean-holdings

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: # Price to Earnings (this works)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'section[data-cy-id=report-sub-section-price-to-earnings-ratio-vs-industry]').click()

    text_you_want = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('g > text[font-size="13"]')[2].text

# Price to Book (this doesn't work)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'section[data-cy-id=report-sub-section-price-to-book-ratio-vs-industry]').click()

    text_you_want = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('g > text[font-size="13"]')[2].text